# Duplicating active layer and adding definition query using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis

**Using:** QGIS version 2.12.0-Lyon. **No Add-on available.**

**Problem:** I do not know where to start after opening the Python console with regards to writing a script that creates a new layer per value queried from a field within QGIS Desktop. I have experience with arcpy and am trying to start with a basic scripted action to learn Python for QGIS.

At the moment I can list all the attributes found in the "active" layer see below:

```
lyr = iface.activeLayer()

features = lyr.getFeatures()

for feat in features:
    attrs = feat.attributes()
    print attrs[1]
```

However, I would like to iterate this and create a new memory layer (i.e. only available whilst the project is open) per feature per attribute creating a new layer where a query is set to equal that attribute (i.e. Name = feat[0])

Can anyone assist in building a template script solution?

*This can be partly completed without using Python by using the "Split Vector Layer" tool. However, this tool will create a folder of shapefiles and not "in memory" layers.*

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173936/how-to-create-memory-layer-and-populate-fields for creating a duplicate memory layer.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that this question has already been answered find it here:

[Duplicate a layer applying a filter in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/174388/duplicate-a-layer-applying-a-filter-in-qgis?rq=1)